# OL3 - ol.interaction.modify - showing labels during drag

Tags: openlayers-3

While modifying a feature with dragging (e.g. moving a point of a polygon), I would like to show the distances of the modified vertices. I intend to use an overlay with some div elements in the proper position on the map (much like the measure example: http://openlayers.org/en/v3.12.1/examples/measure.html?q=measure).

The things I think that are needed for this, is to attach to the proper events (modifystart, modifyend, change:geometry, ...), and being able to determine which vertices are being modified. For each vertex/segment, I can then put such a label on the map.

I would like to know what the best method is to achieve this (mainly to determine which vertices are being modified)? This seems difficult to achieve.

Some options I was investigating:

- The easiest way would be to have access to the dragSegments_ member of the modify interaction. Sadly this seems not to be exposed from the API. For example it would have been nice if some modifydrag event existed, that contained this dragSegments_ collection. Or that this had been already a member of the existing ModifyEvent (not sure whether at the time the modifystart event is raised, this dragSegments_ collection is already filled in).
- I know I can listen to the modifystart and modifyend event. This has a mapBrowserPointerEvent member, which I can use to know the coordinate of the mouse cursor. However, in that case I would have to write some logic to find all the segments matching that coordinate, of the features that are being modified. So in fact, I'm rewriting the same code as the modify interaction used to determine the dragSegments_ collection. And then have to hope that I end up with the same collection as the internal dragSegments_ (and keep this up-to-date with future OL3 code changes).
- I can also listen to the change:geometry events of the features being modified. In that case I would have to scan the new geometry, and compare each point with the original version (store a copy when modification started), and see which coordinates changed. Not sure how good an approach this is (looks ugly at first sight to scan through all the points and compare them one-on-one).

Is there an elegant solution for this?

Comment: Take a look at [ol.interaction.Pointer](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.12.1/apidoc/ol.interaction.Pointer.html). You can use handleDownEvent to detect the feature and handleDragEvent to access dragCoordinate and find delta to translate geometry.

Comment: Thanks for the hint.  
Now when I create an instance of ol.interaction.Pointer as well, and handle these events, I still have to write code to determine which are the segments that are being modified. I.e. I have the drag coordinate, but then I still have to determine which segments of which features are corresponding to this coordinate. So I still end up trying to come up with my own dragSegments_ collection.  
Although I agree that using this, makes it a little bit easier than attaching to the change:geometry. So I think you hint would already be an improvement.